# Data not getting Exporting Excel to SQL server in SSIS and showing no Errors/ Warnings

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I'm trying to export Excel data to SQL server in SSIS 2008.

After executing the package, it is not showing any error or warning. But still the data in the excel is not getting exported to SQL server. I also made sure that i saved the workbook.

After creating the source and the connection manager. The preview of the source is empty.

[image]

The dataviewers are also not getting shown up.

After executing the package,

[image]

These are the execution results
[image]

But still the data in the Excel is not getting exported to SQL.

Comment: Check the Excel source. There must be a configuration problem, or it can be pointing to an empty excel. You should see the data in the data viewers. Please, add more infor on how you've configured the excel data source, and how your excel looks like.

Comment: If the preview is empty, then you must be pointing to the wrong file or the wrong sheet.